# Update child component DOM from parent on animation update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have set up the following Codepen for reference:
[Animate React Ref GSAP](https://codepen.io/euan-cowie/pen/ExgyKLO?editors=0010)

I have a React project I'm working on in which, for sake of example, there exist 2 Components: a Pitch (as in a soccer pitch) and a Player. The Pitch is the parent to the Player, and a `forwardRef()` is used to manage the animation of each player that could be on the pitch from the Pitch component itself.

As you'll also see in the Player component `render()`. The SVG contains a `<g id="Position">...</g>` grouping in which the position of the circle should be updated as the animation progresses. This is where I'm at a loss.

In this project I'm using GSAP to manage the animations, but it could be any animation library really - maybe even none if I were to animate by re-render of Player components by state change, but performance may then be a worry. GSAP provides an `onUpdate` option to its `timeline.to()` function call. It could be possible to read the position values off the SVG from the ref but it would be bad practice to then try to update its DOM from the parent using `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component)` [[reference]](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode).

Thus, my questions really boil down to this:

- If it is not best practice to affect the DOM of the child element (I believe it is not even possible from a functional component, according to ESLint on strict) directly from the parent, then how should I manage it?

  - Should the animation be triggered in the child?
  - Or, should I somehow re-render from the state of the parent?

If I haven't made myself perfectly clear please let me know and I'll do my best to clarify anything or everything!

Comment: Is your question how to read the instantaneous position of the child? Or is it more along the lines of what is the best solution to animate the child?

Comment: Best solution to animate multiple children on a single timeline, would probably be the most succinct way to phrase it

Answer (score 1):

There are few key principles that you should follow when you design React component.

1. State is the source of truth, so how your component display (rendered) is entirely up to how data in state (& prop) looks like. There should never be a case that one state can render into different ways.

With that in mind, having this code `timeline.to(playerRef.current, { x: 0, y: 0, duration: 2 });` is not really "The react way" because it doesn't store player position into a state, but use another thing (gsap) to manipulate how things display (x,y position)

This is more React way

```
// Pitch
const Pitch = () => {
  const defaultPosition = { x: 210, y: 136 }
  const [playerPosition, setPlayerPosition] = useState(defaultPosition);
  
  const playMe = () => {
    setPlayerPosition({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  };

  const resetMe = () => {
    setPlayerPosition(defaultPosition);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onClick={playMe}>Play</button>
      <button type="button" onClick={resetMe}>Reset</button>
      <hr />
      <svg width="420px" height="272px" viewBox="0 0 420 272">
        <g id="Pitch">
          <rect id="Pitch-Background" fill="#409D41" x="0" y="0" width="420" height="272"></rect>
        </g>
        <Player position={playerPosition} />
      </svg>
    </>
  );

}
```

### So the next question will be "How to we manage animation then?"

90% of the animations in React Component, you will want to animation between states. A transition between state A to state B.

In terms of managing animation in react, I can break down into 3 groups.

1. Transition from predefined state A to predefined state B
   (ex. div open x = 200 to div close x = 0)
2. Transition from state A to state B dynamically (ex. move to where mouse click happen)
3. A timeline/sequences of animation between state A to state B (ex. three elements has to animate one after another to fulfill the whole animation sequence)

---

If your use-case fall into 1. then css `transition` is your answer.

If your use-case fall into 2. then css `transition` can be your answer, or some animation library such as `react-motion`, `react-spring`, `framer motion`, etc.

If your use-case fall into 3. then GSAP Timeline is your big boy. BUT there's a certain way to write this. Which I won't get into detail at this point.

---

Again, in your example... let's say it's 2. (Transition from state A to state B dynamically). We can solve this with css `transition`.

```
const Player = ({ position }) => {
  return (
    <g
      style={{ transition: `all 1s ease-out` }}
      transform={`translate(${newPosition.x},${newPosition.y})`}
    >
      <circle id="Oval" fill="#FF0000" cx="23" cy="39" r="19.5"></circle>
    </g>
}
```

Here's the working code from what I describe.
https://codepen.io/Doppy/pen/XWjNmdB

PS. I added in the example of how to make player move to a position of mouse click too :)

Have a good day!

Comment: I'm working towards a step-by-step animation that includes multiple elements with the changing of direction, speed etc etc. So a timeline is the most ideal pattern I believe. The management of animation flow (pause, reverse, etc) are possible in CSS transitions but require some manual work. I know you said you won't get in to it at this point but could you perhaps point to some resource about how one might handle this?

Comment: Before going into timeline, I suggest you take a look at concept of "spring" animation first, it's another concept that solve animation that duration cannot solve. I believe it might be the one you're looking for. https://github.com/framer/motion.  or https://www.react-spring.io/

Comment: Hmm. Spring animation is almost certainly not what I'm after. I want to manage the duration of Linear eased animation (literally just moving the elements). Each element needs a starting point in time and a duration. This is why I think using GSAP Timeline or making my own Timeline are the only options that makes sense